# Chrome Extension Facebook messages

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I am making chrome extension that open facebook profile send friend request and need to send message to that person. I am not sure how to implement facebook api or how to send facebook message to that person that profile is opened ( meesage that needs to be sent will be inserted in the textbox in the extension)

Thanks in advance

I tried looking for facebook api sending messages but that is only a webhook to say, only for pages when someone send's a message to bot response

Comment: why not just use the regular way of sending a friend request? what's the benefit? automatic friend requests and auto-messages are spam anyway and not allowed.

Comment: Hey UnitedEmpire, welcome to SO! You should try to break your question into little modules so that it's easier also for other people to find answers. Anyways, you could open the FB page and then fill the textbox by injecting a content script on the FB page, but I think that would be definitely considered spam and not allowed by FB.

Comment: I would send messages to people from the list who singed up for challenge that's a reason not to spam random people